# How to protect against billion laugh attack in SVG that uses xlink in PHP or javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

I want to protect my site against billion laugh attack.
the code of the SVG image that makes the attack is:

```
<svg version="1.2" baseProfile="tiny" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" xml:space="preserve">
<path id="a" d="M0,0"/>
<g id="b"><use xlink:href="#a"/><use xlink:href="#a"/><use xlink:href="#a"/><use xlink:href="#a"/><use xlink:href="#a"/><use xlink:href="#a"/><use xlink:href="#a"/><use xlink:href="#a"/><use xlink:href="#a"/><use xlink:href="#a"/></g>
<g id="c"><use xlink:href="#b"/><use xlink:href="#b"/><use xlink:href="#b"/><use xlink:href="#b"/><use xlink:href="#b"/><use xlink:href="#b"/><use xlink:href="#b"/><use xlink:href="#b"/><use xlink:href="#b"/><use xlink:href="#b"/></g>
<g id="d"><use xlink:href="#c"/><use xlink:href="#c"/><use xlink:href="#c"/><use xlink:href="#c"/><use xlink:href="#c"/><use xlink:href="#c"/><use xlink:href="#c"/><use xlink:href="#c"/><use xlink:href="#c"/><use xlink:href="#c"/></g>
<g id="e"><use xlink:href="#d"/><use xlink:href="#d"/><use xlink:href="#d"/><use xlink:href="#d"/><use xlink:href="#d"/><use xlink:href="#d"/><use xlink:href="#d"/><use xlink:href="#d"/><use xlink:href="#d"/><use xlink:href="#d"/></g>
<g id="f"><use xlink:href="#e"/><use xlink:href="#e"/><use xlink:href="#e"/><use xlink:href="#e"/><use xlink:href="#e"/><use xlink:href="#e"/><use xlink:href="#e"/><use xlink:href="#e"/><use xlink:href="#e"/><use xlink:href="#e"/></g>
<g id="g"><use xlink:href="#f"/><use xlink:href="#f"/><use xlink:href="#f"/><use xlink:href="#f"/><use xlink:href="#f"/><use xlink:href="#f"/><use xlink:href="#f"/><use xlink:href="#f"/><use xlink:href="#f"/><use xlink:href="#f"/></g>
<g id="h"><use xlink:href="#g"/><use xlink:href="#g"/><use xlink:href="#g"/><use xlink:href="#g"/><use xlink:href="#g"/><use xlink:href="#g"/><use xlink:href="#g"/><use xlink:href="#g"/><use xlink:href="#g"/><use xlink:href="#g"/></g>
<g id="i"><use xlink:href="#h"/><use xlink:href="#h"/><use xlink:href="#h"/><use xlink:href="#h"/><use xlink:href="#h"/><use xlink:href="#h"/><use xlink:href="#h"/><use xlink:href="#h"/><use xlink:href="#h"/><use xlink:href="#h"/></g>
<g id="j"><use xlink:href="#i"/><use xlink:href="#i"/><use xlink:href="#i"/><use xlink:href="#i"/><use xlink:href="#i"/><use xlink:href="#i"/><use xlink:href="#i"/><use xlink:href="#i"/><use xlink:href="#i"/><use xlink:href="#i"/></g>
</svg>
```

I need to find a PHP or a javascript solution that protects the site against this without the prevention of the SVG file upload.
the image is embedded in my website in img tag

Comment: Since there are so many different things that can be done to the XML, you should just test for the extensions you accept and limit the file size. Don't allow write access to the folder, except by admin.

Comment: Hi, I think you could read the file, and test its contents against some of the malicious contents to pretend it is malicious and eject it. See how to read binary files in PHP and use `str_pos` to test the contents.

Answer (score 0):

Because this attack works by consuming a large amount of memory, you should try processing the SVG in a separate process that has a strict memory limit. If the memory of the process is exhausted then you know the SVG is bad.

You can set the memory limit of a single PHP process during runtime with:

```php
ini_set('memory_limit','16M');
```

This would set the memory limit of the process to 16M.

Comment: the svg is not loaded in the back end to set a limit

Answer (score 0):

### DOM parsing might help

The following example uses `xPath` to parse the raw svg/xml markup. Its nodes are then queried to find suspicious patterns.

```php
<?php

function detectSVGBillionLaugh($svgMarkup, $maxUseAllowed = 5000)
{

    // replace xlink:href
    $svgMarkup = str_replace('xlink:href', 'href', $svgMarkup);
    $namespace = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';


    /**
     * Check for the existence of an XML prologue and an entity definition.
    */ 

    // not per se bad
    $hasPrologue = preg_match('/\<\?xml.+\?\>|\<\!DOCTYPE.+]\>/i', $svgMarkup);

    // probably not that relevant anymore
    $hasEntity = preg_match('/\<\!ENTITY/i', $svgMarkup);


    /**
     * add namespace for parsing if not existing
     * if no namespace is defined save it to namespace variable
     * no name space can cause issues for standalone svg embedding
     * e.g in img tags or editors
     */ 
    $hasNamespace = 1;
    if (strpos($svgMarkup, $namespace) === false) {
        $svgMarkup = str_replace('<svg ', '<svg xmlns="' . $namespace . '" ', $svgMarkup);
        $hasNamespace = 0;
    }

    // Load the SVG markup into a DOMDocument.
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadXML($svgMarkup);

    // Create an XPath object to query the SVG content.
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
    $xpath->registerNamespace('svg', 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg');

    // Replace xlink:href with href to simplify parsing.
    $svgMarkup = str_replace('xlink:href', 'href', $svgMarkup);

    // all use elements in the SVG.
    $useElsAll = $xpath->query('//svg:use')->length;

    // Defs with multiple <use> elements
    $groupedUseDefs = $xpath->query('//svg:g|//svg:symbol[svg:use and count(.//svg:use) > 1]');

    // Count nonsensical paths - typically used in billion laugh svg
    $nonsensePaths = $xpath->query('//svg:path[@d="M0,0" or @d="M0 0"]')->length;


    /**
     * additional checks:
     * - file size
     * - nonsense paths
     * - scripts
     * - foreign objects
     * - external hrefs
     * - animations
     * - filters
     */
    // Count the occurrences of rendered elements
    $geometryElements = $xpath->query('//svg:path | //svg:rect | //svg:circle | //svg:ellipse | //svg:line | //svg:polygon | //svg:polyline | //svg:image | //svg:text')->length;

    // search potential performance killers like animations and filters
    $animations = $xpath->query('//svg:animate | //svg:animateMotion | //svg:animateColor | //svg:animateTransform')->length;
    $filters = $xpath->query('//svg:filter')->length;

    $foreignObjects = $xpath->query('//svg:foreignObject')->length;
    $scripts = $xpath->query('//svg:script')->length;
    $fileSize = round(strlen($svgMarkup) / 1024, 3);

    // external hrefs
    $allHrefs = $xpath->query('//svg:*[@href]');
    $externalHrefs = [];
    foreach ($allHrefs as $el) {
        $href = $el->getAttribute('href');
        if (strpos($href, 'http') !== false) {
            $externalHrefs[] = $href;
        }
    }


    // report/summary
    $score_billionLaugh = 0;
    $report = [
        'useNested' => 0,
        'useDefsNested' => $groupedUseDefs->length,
        'useEls' => $useElsAll,
        'nested' => [],
        'nonsensePaths' => $nonsensePaths,
        'isBillionLaugh' => false,
        'score_billionLaugh' => $score_billionLaugh,

        //additional info
        'hasPrologue' => $hasPrologue,
        'hasEntity' => $hasEntity,
        'hasNamespace' => $hasNamespace,
        'fileSize' => $fileSize,
        'filters' => $filters,
        'scripts' => $scripts,
        'geometryElements' => $geometryElements,
        'foreignObjects' => $foreignObjects,
        'externalHrefs' => count($externalHrefs),
        'animations' => $animations,
    ];


    /**
     * first run:
     * collect all use reference IDs
     * prevents failures detecting shuffled 
     * billion laugh definitions
     */
    $totalEls = 0;
    $refIdObj = [];

    foreach ($groupedUseDefs as $el) {
        $useEls = $xpath->query('.//svg:use', $el);
        $id = $el->getAttribute('id');
        $refIds = [];

        //all IDs refrenced by use href attributes
        foreach ($useEls as $use) {
            $href = $use->getAttribute('href');
            $refId = str_replace('#', '', $href);
            $refIds[] = $refId;
        }

        // first definition use instance
        $firstUseRefId = $refIds[0];
        if (!isset($refIdObj[$firstUseRefId])) {
            $refIdObj[$firstUseRefId] = ['refIds' => [$firstUseRefId]];
        }
        $refIdObj[$id] = ['refIds' => $refIds];
    }

    /**
     * second run:
     * calculate rendered elements
     * based on nested referencing
     */
    foreach ($refIdObj as $id => $refObj) {
        $currentTotal = 0;
        $refIds = $refObj['refIds'];

        foreach ($refIds as $refId) {
            if (!isset($report['nested'][$refId])) {
                $occurrence = isset($refIdObj[$refId]) ? count($refIdObj[$refId]['refIds']) : 1;
                $report['nested'][$refId] = ['total' => $occurrence];
            }
            $currentTotal += $report['nested'][$refId]['total'];
        }

        $totalEls += $currentTotal;
        $report['nested'][$id] = ['total' => $currentTotal];
        $report['useNested'] = $totalEls;
    }


    /**
     * calculate a score
     * including other indicators
     */

    // most important indicator
    if ($report['useNested'] > $maxUseAllowed || $report['useEls'] > $maxUseAllowed) {
        $report['isBillionLaugh'] = true;
        $score_billionLaugh += 20;
    }

    if ($nonsensePaths) {
        $score_billionLaugh += $nonsensePaths * 2;
    }

    if ($nonsensePaths === $geometryElements) {
        $score_billionLaugh += $nonsensePaths * 2;
    }

    if ($groupedUseDefs->length > 5 && $useElsAll > 50) {
        $score_billionLaugh += 1;
    }

    if ($groupedUseDefs->length > 5 && $geometryElements === 1) {
        $score_billionLaugh += 2;
    }

    $report['score_billionLaugh'] = $score_billionLaugh;
    return $report;
}
```

#### How the detection works

We can apply some heuristic search patterns but most importantly the above script calculates the total amount of rendered `<use>` elements introduced by nested references/definitions.

We basically use a 2 pass scan:

1. we scan all use references and create a lookup object/associative array (please bear with me in JS it would be an object) to store occurences of each referenced id (see first run).
2. we create a report array/object to store/cache previous occurrence calculations
3. now as we know which use reference points to other use references we can loop through all references – constantly reading and updating the previous total sum of elements (see second run).

Admittedly, this might be quite clunky but you won't need a recursive search that might eventually trap you in a quite expensive loop.
Besides, this detection will also work for "shuffled" use nestings – e.g.
#j, #b, #c, #e, #f, #a, #g, #i, #h, #d

#### Other suspicious patterns

- **nonsense paths** `d="M 0 0"` or `d="M 0,0"` is plain nonsense: this doesn't render anything – suspicious
- number of self contained renderable elements:

  - geometry elements: `path`,`rect`, `circle`, `ellipse`, `polygon`, `polyline`, `line`
  - elements with self contained visual properties: `image`, `text`
    If we only have one of these elements present but a lot of use references – strong indicator.
    **ToDo:** include nonsense primitives like `<rect>`, `<circle>` etc. without reasonable attribute values.
- the ratio between the aforementioned renderable elements and the amount of `<use>` elements
- the sum of use references including multiple `<use>` elements

#### Basic test file: block form file uploads

We take the temporary file to parse and validate it. If the file is evaluated as suspicious we stop processing i.e. reject saving the file input to a database or as a static file to the server.

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="image" type="file" accept="image/svg+xml">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<?php
require_once 'validateSvg.php';

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST") {

    $image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $image_tmp = $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];
    $uploadPath = "uploads/" . $image;

    // analyze svg from temporary file
    $file_content = file_get_contents($image_tmp);

    if ($file_content) {
        $report = detectSVGBillionLaugh($file_content);
        $score = $report['score_billionLaugh'];

        // valid - upload file
        if ($score <= 2) {
            $uploaded = move_uploaded_file($image_tmp, $uploadPath);
            if ($uploaded) {
                echo '<h3>File uploaded</h3>';
            } else {
                echo '<h3>File could not be uploaded</h3>';
            }
        }

        // don't upload
        else {
            $feedback = 'SVG file is slightly suspicious';

            if ($score > 5) {
                $feedback = 'Svg file is highly supsicious!';
            }
            echo $feedback;
        }
    }
    echo '<pre>'.
    print_r($report, true).
    '</pre>';
}
?>
```

#### How "SVG billion laugh attacks" work

- **`<use>`** instances will always have a significant impact on rendering performance – this is rather negligible (or not noticeable) if used in a *reasonable* manner (i.e. using only a few use elements)
- this exploit creates **nested use references/definitions** and multiplies the total amount of rendered elements on each iteration to a sum of more than one billion elements (...hence the name I guess):

```
    #a: 1
    #b: 10
    #c: 100
    #d: 1000
    #e: 10000
    #f: 100000
    #g: 1000000
    #h: 10000000
    #i: 100000000
    #j: 1000000000
    Sum: 1 111 111 111 rendered elements
```

- **hard to detect:**

  - filesize: in fact pretty lightweight
  - total amount of elements: ~ 100 `<use>` elements – not alarming